# Converting from sign-magnitude to two's complement

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

For this assignment I can only use basic bitwise operators and no control structures, so I've come up with this code so far to convert sign-magnitude to [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

```
int sm2tc(int x) {
    // Invert and add 1
    // Problem: sm has 2 zeros.. 1000...000 & 0000...000
    int tmin = 1 << 31;
    int mask = x >> 31;  // Determine sign of x
    int mask2 = ~tmin; // Negate tmin to get 0111111...
    int first = (x ^ mask) + (~mask + 1) ;
    int second = first & mask2; // Turns of MSB
    return second;
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on an `int` being 32 bits. Use `int32_t` to be sure (`stdint.h`).

Comment: The code is being run on a 32 bit linux machine for grading and on my machine.  If I wanted this to be portable I think I could use (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) to store the bit value.

Comment: If the purpose of the exercise is to have well-defined bit operations and impose your own interpretations of signedness upon the bits, you should really be using unsigned types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you really want to compute is

```
result = (x & sign_bit) ? -(x & ~sign_bit) : x;
```

But of course you're not allowed control structures. The first step is to rewrite `-(x & ~sign_bit)` using just the `+` and `^` operators: `(-1 ^ (x & ~sign_bit)) - -1`. Now note that if `(x & sign_bit)` is zero then `(0 ^ (x & ~sign_bit)) - 0` is equal to `x`. We now have

```
result = (x & sign_bit) ? (-1 ^ (x & ~sign_bit)) - -1 : (0 ^ (x & ~sign_bit)) - 0
```

You then just need to replace the `-1` and `0` with functions of `x` that generate those values depending on the sign bit, and lo and behold both sides of the condition become the same expression and the condition becomes unnecessary.

Comment: You are assuming that the underlying platform is based on 2's complement representation. Why are you making that assumption? Why aren't you assuming that the platform is actually based on signed-magnitude? I'd say that a "clean" solution for this specific problem should not rely on any specifics of the platform. For example, your original expression is a no-op on a signed-magnitude platform.

Comment: What we see in OP's post is a clear attempt to make a platform-independent solution. So, what you did is not exactly what OP needs. In other words, you are not allowed to rely on `-x` producing 2's complement representation, i.e. unary `-` is prohibited.

Comment: Your explanation is great.  All I had to do was switch the line where I unset the MSB to before the actual conversion

Comment: @AndreyT You are correct in that I was using a 2's complement machine for my explanation, but I did at least eliminate the troublesome unary minus in my first step although I agree I should have used `~0` instead of `-1`.

Comment: @Neil This thread is a bit old...I have the same question with the OP so I found here...I have a question of the answer, why don't just write the code like `result = (x & sign_bit) ? (~(x & ~sign_bit))+1 : x` ? Why need to add `-0` and `0^` ? Thank you.

Comment: @eepty `?:` is a control structure and therefore disallowed by the OP's original question.